# Blend Modes for Sound

Tags: audio, mixing

With image data, there are [blend modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together). I was wondering if there is something similar for audio? That is, if I have a high sound and a low sound, roughly speaking, could I: lighten (return the high sound), darken (return the low sound), or difference (return the "distance" between the two sounds)?

Answer (score 1):

Low- and Hi-pass filters, and EQ will let you return high or low frequencies very easily. You can remove any frequency range.

I'm not sure it will do what you expect if you are thinking of it in terms of blending for images, but it is well worth playing around with filters and EQ so you see what can be done.

"Difference" is a bit of a challenge. There is such a function, ring modulation, which does take sum and difference of two input frequencies, and you could input the high and low frequencies that you separate out with a filter. However it will almost certainly sound terrible, as frequencies need fairly simple mathematical relationship to sound "good"